# Read cookie created by Java app from Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I'm trying to read a cookie created by a Java app from Asp.Net but not having much luck

I'm using this line of code:

```
string CoockieValue = Response.Cookies["Cookie_Name"].Value;
```

Is this possible at all ?

We basically have an authentication web ui developed in java and there is a url that takes to an Asp.Net page that needs to read this cookie

Please advise

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't a cookie a cookie, regardless of what is used to create or read it?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible at all ?

Yes, if both applications are hosted on the same domain. If not, then, no, it is not possible. 
When setting a cookie there are 2 properties: `path` and `domain` which could be specified in order to limit the scope of the cookie.

So for example when in your Java application you set the cookie with `domain="foo.com"`, all application on any subdomain on `foo.com` will be able to read it. So if you Java application is hosted on `java.foo.com` and your ASP.NET application is hosted on `asp.foo.com` it will be able to access it.